# Formula evaluation returns weird value

Tags: excel-formula, evaluation, week-number, excel-2021

I created a formula in excel to get the iso.weeknumber in 2 numbers:

```
=JAAR(A2)&" "&ALS(LENGTE(ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2)=1);"0"&ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2);ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2))
```

The result is this:

[image]

somehow, Excel thinks week 10 is length 1 in this formula. I checked, and only the length of weeknumber of the used date is 2 (see value in column N).

I then started formula evaluation and that is where something weird happens:
[image]

[image]

the result is false. but then this happens:

[image]

where does that 6 come from?

Comment: It is pretty hard to read the dutch formula ... so I can't explain the error. But why don't you use `TEXT` like this: `=YEAR(A1)&" "&TEXT(ISOWEEKNUM(A1),"00")`   ( `=JAAR(A1)&" "&TEKST(ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A1);"00")`  )

Comment: The `English` Version of this formula: `=YEAR(A2)&" "&IF(LEN(ISOWEEKNUM(A2)=1),"0"&ISOWEEKNUM(A2),ISOWEEKNUM(A2))` and you do `=YEAR(A2)&" "&BASE(ISOWEEKNUM(A2),2,2)` in `Dutch` --> `=JAAR(A2)&" "&BASIS(ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2);2;2)`

Comment: Ok - your error is that you evaluate the length of true/false: try `ALS(ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2)=1; ....`

Comment: Sorry the `radix` in `BASE()` function will be `10` you can use this `=YEAR(A2)&" "&BASE(ISOWEEKNUM(A2),10,2)` it will work as per requirements, i believe so. In `Dutch` --> `=JAAR(A2)&" "&BASIS(ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2);10;2)`

Comment: thanks, however, I created the formula in a new unformatted column, and then it works as it should: =JAAR(A2)&" "&ALS(LENGTE(ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2))<2;0&ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2);ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2))

(however I changed =1 to <2)

Comment: @DutchArjo if its working then post it as answer and accept it by ticking the tickmark beside it, the same so it helps someone in the future if one is looking for a solution like your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the formula in a new unformatted column, and then it works as it should:

```
=JAAR(A2)&" "&ALS(LENGTE(ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2))<2;0&ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2);ISO.WEEKNUMMER(A2))
```